# Control Your Computer's Fan Speed

Tags: code-golf

The objective of this question is to create a program that pushes your computer's internal fan speed to its maximum RPM.  Upon exiting the program, your fan should return to the normal operating RPM.

**Rules:**

1. You may not perform a CPU intensive task in order to modify the
   fan's speed.
2. Exiting the program may be via user input, a timeout period, or a response to a `SIGTERM` or `SIGEXIT` signal.
3. Avoid [the standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/1061/10844).

Comment: How should the program exit? Timeout? User input? Signal?

Comment: @GregHewgill No requirement is put in place on that, whatever takes the fewest number of characters would make an optimal solution however.

Comment: Then probably the fewest number of characters would be a program that never exits, since exiting is not actually required.

Comment: @GregHewgill The program can run infinitely, sure.  But if I kill the program from outside the sandbox in which it runs, then the fan should return to the normal operating RPM.

Comment: See, that's what I was asking about. :) So is responding to signals a requirement? Which signals? Signal 9 on a POSIX platform might be challenging to react to.

Comment: @GregHewgill It is not a requirement.  Let your execution environment manage the handling of SIGTERM, SIGSTOP and the like.

Comment: Now, I'm not an expert on this, never actually implemented code to control your own hardware, but wouldn't "Max" fan speed differ from person to person?  If I write code to max my own fan speed, but your fan can do better, have I still won?

Comment: Do you have good reason to believe that this is possible?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I mean, it's possible given a pre-installment of lm_sensors, and then to run a bash script, but I don't know the rules about installing anything to help your program :/

Comment: @user3334871, controlling the fan speed is possible. The bit I'm dubious about is resetting it to normal when the program is killed without any opportunity to react.

Comment: huge side-effect as a primary target - not a pure programming puzzle.

Comment: I suspect very strongly that in order to meet this requirement, the program would need to be closed in a controlled manner. As far as I'm aware, this is no way to capture an unmanaged process termination.

Comment: "computer's internal fan speed", which fan?

Comment: Wouldn't a signal handler help?  Or a process that monitors the original process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## OSX + Bash + [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl), 91 bytes

This relies on the third-party [smcFanControl](https://github.com/hholtmann/smcFanControl) suite to do the hard work **and is therefore more of a proof-of-concept** than a serious answer.  **Real** answers could pick apart the smcFanControl source code and do this without third-party help.

[smcFanControl.app](http://www.conscius.de/smcfancontrol_2_2_2.zip) is assumed to be installed in `/Applications`.

```
p=/Ap*/smcFan*/C*/R*/smc\ -k # Path to CLI utility
f()($p'FS! ' -w000$1)        # function to set fan mode
f 3                          # Set fan speeds to "forced" mode
eval $p\ F{0,1}"Tg -w5DC0;"  # Set fan 1 and 2 to 6000 RPM target speed
read                         # wait for keyboard input
f 0                          # Return fans to "auto" mode
```

Comments added for explanation, but not included in score.

Comment: depending on your entry the whole point of this contest is to find an utility that has the shortest name and then control the fan with it. how clever one must have to be... 
and this doesn't mean i don't like your answer. i belive it's already a winner. but the whole challenge is pointless.

Comment: DigitalTrauma found a program that can be controlled like that. What if i find (or make but okay, its a loophole) an utility that does the same if I type `maxfan`?

Comment: @bebe All good points.  See my edit.

Comment: basically [Outsourcing the answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1085/13950)

Answer (score 5):

## GLXGEARS - 8bytes

First thing I thought of was `yes`, or `yes` in parallel. As we are not allowed to use the CPU to control the speed, let's use the GPU:

```
glxgears
```

Answer (score 4):

## Reboot, 6 bytes

```
reboot
```

Just after a boot, the fans start spinning at max rpm because the power is turned on to the fan, before the BIOS loads any real time controllers that will base the speed of the fan on the temperature of the processor. This also keeps the processor from getting excessively hot if you were to try the alternative... which would be to keep the fan off until those controllers were loaded and basing the fan speed on processor temp. More of a safeguard than anything. The processor is starting to work the moment you turn the computer on, but the BIOS still needs time to load. https://superuser.com/a/427723/246895

(Does not work on every pc, but is confirm the OP)

Comment: The program exits before the reboot actually occurs, so the fan spin-up happens after program exit. This is not at all in line with the spec.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Completely true.